# How to rename a logical volume when there are multiple volume groups with the same name

Tags: lvm

I installed Fedora 24 on my main drive, but later decided to install it on my solid state drive instead. After doing so, I tried to mount my main drive (after running cryptsetup), but this happened:

```
# lvrename /dev/fedora/home /dev/fedora/althome 
  Multiple VGs found with the same name: skipping fedora 
  Use the VG UUID with --select vg_uuid=<uuid>

# lvdisplay

: above lists my partitions uuids


# lvrename --select vg_uuid=my-vg-uuid /dev/fedora/home /dev/fedora/althome

lvrename: unrecognized option '--select'
```

Since the given instructions don't work, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

Use vgdisplay to find the volume group's UUID (not the logical volume's UUID) and then:

```
vgrename my-vg-id oldfedora
```

This appears to be a bug in Fedora 24.

Comment: In case the command is not found (Synology), try `lvm vgrename` instead of plain `vgrename`.

Comment: by my-vg-id, it means my-vg-uuid just to spare someone the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR - the only thing that works is:

`lvm vgrename <vg uuid from vgdisplay> <new_vg_name>`

Thank you to @koppor!

I too had two `fedora_localhost-live` VGs (pulled the drive out of a smoked machine and trying to get data off of it.).

I tried about 15 different combinations with `vgrename` then about 5 with `lvm vgrename`

The only one that works is this:

```
# vgdisplay
<snip>
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora_localhost-live
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               236.87 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              60639
  Alloc PE / Size       60639 / 236.87 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               5UVnsQ-duSo-0AxN-BXkx-kchz-3LIv-eHb6Cp
# lvm vgrename 5UVnsQ-duSo-0AxN-BXkx-kchz-3LIv-eHb6Cp vg_polonium
```

Comment: This worked for me with KUbuntu 23.04, but just using `vgrename` did not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. I guess this is some sort of bug. Instead of using `--select vg_uuid=<uuid>` use just the `<uuid>` of the vg. The vg_uuid can be found `vgdisplay` command