# Delete volume group of HDD of which the name is the same as my main SSD's

Tags: lvm, hard-disk, kubuntu, disk-encryption

I just bought a new computer with an HDD + SSD. I must've accidentally encrypted the HDD it during installation, although I am sure I did undo it, but here it is, encrypted and even if I put the password it will display the error:

> An error occurred while accessing '930.3 GiB Encrypted Drive', the system responded: An unspecified error has occurred: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem' on object at path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d3

So I want to remove it. It has nothing in it, since it is a brand new computer, and it was when I found out about `lvremove` and `lvscan`, but `lvscan` shows me the following:

```
root@gabriel:/home/gabriel# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/kubuntu-vg/root' [117.04 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/kubuntu-vg/swap_1' [976.00 MiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/kubuntu-vg/root' [<929.34 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/kubuntu-vg/swap_1' [976.00 MiB] inherit
```

**df**

```
root@gabriel:/home/gabriel# df
Filesystem                   1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           3999308       0   3999308   0% /dev
tmpfs                           806208    1664    804544   1% /run
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root 120276728 8690824 105433100   8% /
tmpfs                          4031032   65164   3965868   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          4031032       0   4031032   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2                       721392  150632    518296  23% /boot
/dev/sda1                       523248    6228    517020   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                           806204       0    806204   0% /run/user/119
tmpfs                           806204      12    806192   1% /run/user/1000
```

**gparted**

[image]

I tried `lvremove` /dev/sda(1):

```
root@gabriel:/home/gabriel# lvremove /dev/sda(1)
  Volume group "sda(1)" not found
  Cannot process volume group sda(1)
```

*the (1) means I tried with "sda" and "sda1". I also attempted with 3, but same message.*

I am supposing the volume group would be the `/dev/kubuntu-vg/root|swap_1`, but they are duplicated. How do I remove the logical volume of my HDD?

Comment: Are you trying to delete your root partition while running the system that is installed on it? AFAIK you cannot delete it that way. Use a live CD and reformat (or do a plain reinstall since it is just brand new)

Comment: Well, I do not know why there is a boot partition in the HDD. That is supposed to be just for storage, like an external HDD, but in the computer. Do I still need to use live CD?

Comment: My system is installed in my SSD, and what I want to remove is the HDD's.

Comment: Sorry missed that you had an active root on the SSD and the rest on the HDD. Did you try using `cfdisk` for repartitioning, yet?  I assume the HDD can be wiped without concern.

Comment: can't make it an answer, try `vgreduce --removemissing kunbunu_vg`

Comment: for lvm namespace clashes, you have to rename by VG UUID, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324414/30851

Comment: Something happened and my SSD was also affected. Shit happened during a clean installation and at this moment I write I erased everything in the SSD with GParted and the installation is running again.

Comment: Finished installation and now things seem to be alright. I really must've selected the HDD accidentally and might've encrypted and I did not see, even though I did select SSD. After the attempt to use `cfdisk`, somehow the SDD went weird and was not seen on boot, but I am sure to have selected the HDD. Tried a clean install and had an error when installing grub, so I simply wiped everything with GParted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `/dev/sda1` nor `/dev/sda3` are logical volumes. `/dev/sda3` contains a volume group (`kubuntu-vg`), which in turn contains the logical volumes (`root`, `swap_1`, maybe more, maybe less).

You can show the logical volumes with [`lvdisplay`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvdisplay.8.html) or shorter and clearer [`lvs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvs.8.html). Same with volume groups, [`vgdisplay`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgdisplay.8.html) or [`vgs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgs.8.html).

---

To remove a logical volume with [`lvremove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvremove.8.html), you must give the complete path as shown in the example section

```
lvremove kubuntu-vg/root
```

or to remove all logical volumes in this group

```
lvremove kubuntu-vg
```

---

If the logical volumes are still active, you must deactivate them first

```
vgchange --activate n kubuntu-vg/root
```

or *use the force* when removing

```
lvremove --force kubuntu-vg/root
```

---

If there are really two volume groups with the same name, or two logical volumes with the same name, you may need to use the UUID as @frostschutz suggested in comments. This may be shown with `lvdisplay` or, a bit more compact, with

```
lvdisplay | grep -e Path -e UUID
```

Comment: Very interesting. Too bad I did something wrong with `cfdisk`, even having the HDD selected, that affected my SSD and I had to wipe out clean everything in my SDD and make a clean install. Thank you for your answer, I will still select as the correct one because it looks like it is.